# Xamarin references not declared

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've recently started delving into android development with Xamarin, as I already have good c# experience. I've been having so many issues, so i'm wondering if i'm doing something wrong(which I probably am).

First issue I ran into was with the v7 support library. After installing in both xamarin component store, nugget and referencing the dll, I kept getting not declared on every v7 element in my xml. I had of course downloaded the version corresponding to the targeted sdk version.
Anyways, after hours I got it working somehow and I don't even know how.

Now after making this very little progress, I run into the next issue.
I'm trying to make a drawer to display a menu and I've been following this guide
https://blog.xamarin.com/add-beautiful-material-design-with-the-android-support-design-library/
The issue i'm having now, is that i'm trying to make the menu xml file and for some unknown reason, even android:icon is reported as not declared.
I'm having a hard time believing that this would be normal, as I've used hours on pretty much no progress. So i'm wondering if native java development would be a better way to go? Or is it in fact doable to make complex apps on Xamarin, without risking having everything break to a bug?
I would've posted an image, but I can't as I don't have 10 reputation.
Here's the code i'm getting issues on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_home"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
  android:title="Home" />
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
  android:title="Messages" />
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_friends"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
  android:title="Friends" />
<item
  android:id="@+id/nav_discussion"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
  android:title="Discussion" />
</group>
<item android:title="Sub items">
<menu>
  <item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
    android:title="Sub item 1" />
  <item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
    android:title="Sub item 2" />
</menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

Both android:checkableBehavior and android:icon is reported as "attribute not declared"
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the `attribute not declared` problem, it's the intellisense issue. If you've correctly installed the Android SDK, this issue should not effect the compiling of your code since they're defined in Android SDK.

But if you want to make these `attribute not declared` tips away, you can download the following two files:

1. [schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd).
2. [android-layout-xml.xsd](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd).

And then for VS2015, put these two files under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas`.

For VS2017, the path is like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Xml\Schemas`.